# How to get TensorFlow Estimator version using Python code (not CLI)

Tags: python, tensorflow, version, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I can get the versions of TensorFlow and TensorFlow Keras using these code lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf;
print("TensorFlow version:",tf.__version__);
print("TensorFlow Keras version:",tf.keras.__version__);
#print("TensorFlow Estimator version:",tf.estimator.__version__);
```

However, tf.estimator has no __version__ attribute. Is there another way to get TensorFlow Estimator version in Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the tf.estimator module with python 'help' function, the answer is that tf.estimator totally has no VERSION attribute.

```
#python code
import tensorflow as tf;
help(tf.estimator);
```

Output:

```
Help on package tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api.estimator in tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api:

NAME
    tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api.estimator - Estimator: High level tools for working with models.

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    experimental (package)
    export (package)
    inputs (package)

FILE
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/api/estimator/__init__.py
```

It seems the only way is using CLI command, for example:

```
pip3 list | grep tensorflow-estimator
```